# knitr doesn't know new function (r-markdown)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a problem regarding the HTML-output with knitr (r-markdown).

I worked with the function `gamlss` from the package "gamlss", but `knitr` cannot find this function/package. So when I try to make an output with "Knit HTML", it just appears an error message:

> "(error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    couldnt find Function
>   "gamlss"  Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers ->
>   withVisible -> eval -> eval implementation stopped.  "

Has anybody ever dealt with a similar problem?

Answer (score 9):

you have to load the package in the markdown file as well

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(gamlss)
**rest of the code**
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @Ole please accept the answer as a solution if it helped you