# R will not recognize imported datasets in markdown

Tags: r, markdown, graphing

When tested with 'mtcars', markdown will have no problem knitting the code in html, however when I use the name of an imported data set:

````
```{r,echo = FALSE}
names(mtcars)
```
````

I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Fitbit' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

Can anyone help me with why? I get an error every time I try to plot a chunk even though the test run went smoothly as well. If I use a chunk, I get an error with {r} or {r, echo = FALSE}.

Ex:

````
---
title: "Homework"
author: "name"
output: html_document
---


```{r,echo = FALSE}
names(Fitbit)
```
````

Output Error:

```
Quitting from lines 9-10 (Example-Homework-Problem.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'fitbit' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Comment: Are you able to knit the default Rmd template in RStudio?

Comment: Yup! and the example code my professor gave works fine using the template, however the imported datasets for myself will not knit if I want to plot them.

Comment: In the template, you "import" the datasets `cars` and `pressure` and you plot one of them. What is `Fitbit` by the way?

Comment: Yes that is correct! Fitbit is just one of the imported datasets. I called it "Fitbit"

Comment: Okay, then can you provide a more reproducible example?

Comment: Do you import this `Fitbit` from another package? Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25260108/6103040

Comment: F. Privé did my post update help? 

I can paste the dataset as well but it is too long; I am new here so if this would help let me know!

Comment: F. Privé I did what the other post you linked said, and I still receive the same error. I'm not sure why. Even in my professor's template, when I switch the template dataset to this "Fitbit" dataset, I receive this error.

Comment: Yes I have a dataset "fitbit" and "Fitbit" and have tried both; my apologies for the confusion. That could have definitely been a red flag.

Comment: Is the library already installed ?

Comment: @NataliaKhodayari , what is the scope of dataset `fitbit` ie. is it invoked inside markdown itself ? or have you `source`d it

Comment: Mir Mbr Yes it is! Not sure if this is overkill but this is what I have:

{r,echo=FALSE}
View(fitbit)
library(readr)
fitbit <- read_csv("~/Downloads/Fitbit.csv")

Comment: @ParthChaudhary I imported the dataset to R Studio, but I am not sure if you can directly import it in markdown itself or R? 

This is my first day programming with this language; my apologies for the confusion!

Comment: You are viewing it before reading it in R? Seems the problem.

Comment: @NataliaKhodayari , follow [this example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chaudharyparth/6470f9e3f6dee046d11494ad4bd58ed6/raw/ff55d83ae1195489262e2bc995b3efabc6cf415e/new_markdown.rmd) of markdown

Comment: Seems pretty confusing. If the dataset is in a library, just load the library and  call the dataset. If the dataset is a CSV for example, read it and then call it. You should have no error by doing that

Comment: Natalia, what is your `getwd()`?

Comment: @MbrMbr that is probably what I am doing wrong; I'll try to load and call the dataset, I thought I did though.

Comment: @AK88 I am not sure what that is sadly!

Comment: Just type in `getwd()` and post the output :))

Comment: @AK88 [1] "/Users/nataliakhodayari"

Comment: @ParthChaudhary when I use library(data.table) in my markdown file with my datasets it says there is no package names "mydataset.table" unless I am using this wrong. (I tried multiple datasets)

Comment: @NataliaKhodayari, you'll have to `install.packages("data.table")` if the package named `data.table` is not installed

Comment: Save the file on you Desktop and try this: `{r} setwd("C:/Users/nataliakhodayari/Desktop") fitbit <- read_csv("Fitbit.csv") names(Fitbit)` File name is case sensitive.

Comment: @AK88 when I insert it into a chunk I get the error:

Error: unexpected symbol in "setwd("C:/Users/nataliakhodayari/Desktop") fitbit"

Comment: @ParthChaudhary I just installed everything thank you! I still am getting errors unfortunately but hopefully closer to a fix!

Comment: @AK88 I just tried this and it went through, but when I apply:

```{r,echo = FALSE}```

to

```hist(Fitbit$Miles,xlab = "Miles",main = "Overall Miles Traveled")```

I get an error that "Fitbit" was not found. I have two datasets, fitbit and Fitbit, and changed the names accordingly

Comment: can you try with lower case `f` as in `fitbit`: hist(fitbit$Miles,xlab = "Miles",main = "Overall Miles Traveled")

Comment: @AK88 yes, I have:

'{r} 
`setwd("C:/Users/nataliakhodayari/Desktop")`
`fitbit <- read_csv("Fitbit.cv")`
`names(fitbit)`

`
{r, echo=FALSE}
fitbit <- read_csv("~/Downloads/Fitbit.csv")
`

and 


`{r,echo = FALSE} hist(fitbit$Miles,xlab = "Miles",main = "Overall Miles Traveled")`

with the same error unfortunately. The error is:

 `object 'fitbit' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> hist`

Comment: @AK88 `read_csv` is in `readr` and OP does not have that loaded. `read.csv` should do fine.

Comment: holy ****, I thought `read_csv` was from `base` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer for your convenience, I will delete it as soon as you try this out:

````
```{r}
setwd("C:/Users/nataliakhodayari/Desktop")
fitbit <- read.csv("Fitbit.csv")
names(fitbit)
hist(fitbit$Miles,xlab = "Miles",main = "Overall Miles Traveled")
```
````

If the directory cannot be changed, try this:

````
```{r}
fitbit <- read.csv("Fitbit.csv")
names(fitbit)
hist(fitbit$Miles,xlab = "Miles",main = "Overall Miles Traveled")
```
````

Comment: I now have the error:

`Error in setwd("") : cannot change working directory`

Comment: I received the error: 'Error in read_csv("Fitbit.csv") : could not find function "read_csv" '

That's bizarre to me that this would be an error!

Comment: No worries; I appreciate you trying!

Comment: Let's give this whole thing another try, thanks to @Axeman. Try the edited code, specifically `read.csv` instead of `read_csv`

Comment: It works now! ^_^  I just have a couple random errors through the knitting process. Thank you!!

`{r,echo = FALSE}
work.marriage.obese.table = table(work$obese,work$marriage)
barplot(work.gender.obese.table,main = "Marriage & Obesity",beside = TRUE,legend = rownames(work.marriage.obese.table))`

will receive the error `object 'work.gender.obese.table' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> barplot`

Comment: this error occurs with the code after this that is the same format. I made work.marriage.obese.table a variable and it is stored in R, so I wonder why this is happening

Comment: Is the file that contains `Marriage & Obesity` data is also csv?

Comment: after changing all the variable names and redoing the code- IT WORKED. I spent 16 hours trying to get plots into html and i'm finally done!! Thank you so much for your help for so many hours! You're a life saver. :)